# Browser Hack stopped working in Fluid Design

Tags: css, media-queries, fluid-layout

I have a small problem with a browser hack, one of my thumbnails needs to be a few pixels lower in webkit browsers than Firefox and it works fine on its own like this:

```
#thumbsicon
{
position: absolute;
margin: 596px 0px 0px 150px;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
#thumbsicon
{
position: absolute;
margin: 525px 0px 0px 150px;
opacity:0.6;
}
}
```

But when i updated the CSS with @media all and (max-height: 640px) for fluid response design,
and i copy/paste the css in and update the margins for the respective new sizes, Webkit browsers ignores all the webkit css hacks.

(this is a trimmed version)

```
@media all and (max-height: 640px) 
{

#thumbsicon
{
position: absolute;
margin: 596px 0px 0px 150px;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
background: yellow;
}


@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
#thumbsicon
{
position: absolute;
margin: 525px 0px 0px 150px;
opacity:0.6;
}
}
}
```

No mistakes in the code, spend two days looking and googling... Do hacks not work when using @media all

Or perhaps there is a semantic mistake i am blindly ignoring?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you put a hack for IE8 in a @media call, if IE8 is never on a mobile browser? I'd recommend just keeping it static.

Comment: It is mainly to deal with different screen sizes and browswer windows sizes IE8 is just in there as a back up for whoever cant find firefox on the internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd `@media` is in the first one.
Change to:

```
@media all and (max-height: 640px) {
    #thumbsicon {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 596px 0px 0px 150px;
        opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
        background: yellow;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #thumbsicon {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 525px 0px 0px 150px;
        opacity:0.6;
    }
}
```

or to:

```
@media all and (max-height: 640px) {
    #thumbsicon {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 596px 0px 0px 150px;
        opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
        background: yellow;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (max-height: 640px) {
    #thumbsicon {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 525px 0px 0px 150px;
        opacity:0.6;
    }
}
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HHP2h/).

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. I actually had this as a solution but messed up with all the brackets. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, please [mark it as the accepted answer](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png).